# ImportError: No module named Image

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I have also tried

```
from PIL import Image
```

but it gives me ImportError: No module named PIL.

I have installed PIL successfully using

```
pip install pil
```

and I've also installed xcode command line tools. Nothing seem to work.

**Details**:

**Mac OS X 10.9**

**Python 2.7.6**

python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

python is /usr/bin/python

python is /usr/local/bin/python

**Name: PIL**

Version: 1.1.7

Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The PIL distribution is mispackaged for egg installation.

Install [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead, the friendly PIL fork.

Answer (score 0):

On a system with both Python 2 and 3 installed and with `pip2`-installed Pillow failing to provide `Image`, it is possible to install PIL for Python 2 in a way that will solve `ImportError: No module named Image`:

```
easy_install-2.7 --user PIL
```

or

```
sudo easy_install-2.7 PIL
```